# Returning 2 callbacks to scrapy URLs with no HREF tags

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm currently using a CrawlSpider to look for any links and therefore follow them.

In order to crawl urls without HREF tags (plain text) i'm extracting them and then using the following snippet to add them back into the parse method.

```
return scrapy.Request(f'http://{url}')
```

The problem with this method is that the base URL doesn't get called into my other parser method. e.g. example.com doesn't but example.com/example does. I've tried adding a callback into the code (callback=self.url_parser) but then the default parse method isn't called and therefore doesn't crawl and follow links.

Is there a way to pass these href-less links into the default parse method (in order to follow links) but also have them parsed by my parser method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my callback on the rules to parse_start_url and everything worked perfectly